# pause and resume XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest-level2

Here is a working code to preload an MP4 video file on the browser via XHR2. Whenever we execute `preloadMe();` the video starts to preload and composite progress event. and as the file completely loaded `preload.oncomplete` fires and we can detect that.

The problem is I want the ability to `pause` and `resume` the preloading process?
using the abort method terminates the whole request. I want to be able to resume later and continue to download the file at the point I paused it.

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Note: there is not any practical answer on StackOverflow in this subject.

Here is the main code:

```
(function (global, factory) {
    typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module !== 'undefined' ? module.exports = factory() :
    typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ? define(factory) :
    (global.Preload = factory());
}(this, (function () { 'use strict';

    function preloadOne(url, done) {
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', url, true);
        xhr.responseType = 'blob';
        xhr.onprogress = event => {
            if (!event.lengthComputable) return false
            let item = this.getItemByUrl(event.target.responseURL);
            item.completion = parseInt((event.loaded / event.total) * 100);
            item.downloaded = event.loaded;
            item.total = event.total;
            this.updateProgressBar(item);
        };
        xhr.onload = event => {
            let type = event.target.response.type;
            let blob = new Blob([event.target.response], { type: type });
            let url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            let responseURL = event.target.responseURL;
            let item = this.getItemByUrl(responseURL);
            item.blobUrl = url;
            item.fileName = responseURL.substring(responseURL.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
            item.type = type;
            item.size = blob.size;
            done(item);
        };
        xhr.send();
    }

    function updateProgressBar(item) {
        var sumCompletion = 0;
        var maxCompletion = this.status.length * 100;

        for (var itemStatus of this.status) {
            if (itemStatus.completion) {
                sumCompletion += itemStatus.completion;
            }
        }
        var totalCompletion = parseInt((sumCompletion / maxCompletion) * 100);

        if (!isNaN(totalCompletion)) {
            this.onprogress({
                progress: totalCompletion,
                item: item
            });
        }
    }

    function getItemByUrl(rawUrl) {
        for (var item of this.status) {
            if (item.url == rawUrl) return item
        }
    }

    function fetch(list) {  
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.loaded = list.length;
            for (let item of list) {
                this.status.push({ url: item });
                this.preloadOne(item, item => {
                    this.onfetched(item);
                    this.loaded--;
                    if (this.loaded == 0) {
                        this.oncomplete(this.status);
                        resolve(this.status);
                    }
                });
            }
        })
    }

    function Preload() {
        return {
            status: [],
            loaded: false,
            onprogress: () => {},
            oncomplete: () => {},
            onfetched: () => {},
            fetch,
            updateProgressBar,
            preloadOne,
            getItemByUrl
        }
    }

    return Preload;

})));
```

And here is the function to initiate the preloading:

```
function preloadMe(){

const preload = Preload();

preload.fetch([
    'https.../video.mp4'

]).then(items => {
  // use either a promise or 'oncomplete'
  console.log(items);
});

preload.oncomplete = items => {
  console.log(items);
  console.log("The video has been preloaded!");
}

preload.onprogress = event => {
  console.log(event.progress + '%');
}

preload.onfetched = item => {
  console.log(item);
}
};
```

Comment: there is no pause

Comment: you dont have access to the partially file, therefore you can´t continue the download.

Comment: That's so SAD :(

Comment: When I reload the page after aborting the request it resumes????!!!!!